# What are the hypothetical zeros of the Dirichlet eta function

Tags: complex-analysis

My question is: What are the **hypothetical zeros** of the Dirichlet eta function (the alternating zeta function) in the critical strip.  This notion is far from my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since the Dirichlet eta function is the analytic continuation of the zeta function in the critical strip, its zeros there are precisely the zeros of the zeta function there and, according to the R.H., they all have real part equal to $\,0.5\,$ ...

Comment: @ DonAntonio:
I found this now: and the **hypothetical zeros** in the critical strip but not on the critical line, which if they do exist must occur at the vertices of rectangles symmetrical around the x-axis and the critical line and whose multiplicity is unknown. Plese see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function

Comment: This just states that if they do exist then they exist at the vertices of rectangles. However, it is conjectured they do not exist in this form, I. E. If proved the RH shows they only appear on the critical line and $\sigma=1$.